# Magento: remove customer accounts functionalty

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

Magento version 1.9.1.0

I want to completely remove customer account creation, account pages, login pages, everything. Please advise.

Comment: diable the Mage_Customer module in admin panel

Comment: Did that, thanks! But I still see "Account" button on the home page.

Comment: nope, cleared it as well. It is still showing.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it: create or edit your theme’s local.xml file under layout like this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

This will remove My Account top link.

Comment: I also peeked into customer.xml and took the code from there for the account link and added it to local.xml file

But it doesn't work as well. Here's is my code:

`<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>`